# Using Matplotlib to save figures from a separate thread in GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, user-interface, pyside

I was using a QRunnable class to start a separate thread from my gui ( for non-blocking functionality). This thread was using Matplotlib to save some plots as pdfs. However it is giving several warnings

```
    class Results(QRunnable):
        def __init__(self):
        super(Results, self).__init__()


        def run(self):
            plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
            plt.savefig('plot.pdf')

    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
            

            layout = QVBoxLayout()
    
            self.l = QLabel("Start")
            b = QPushButton("DANGER!")
            b.pressed.connect(self.oh_no)

            layout.addWidget(self.l)
            layout.addWidget(b)

            w = QWidget()
            w.setLayout(layout)

            self.setCentralWidget(w)

            self.show()

        def oh_no(self):
            worker = Results()
            self.threadpool.start(worker)


    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

These were the warnings :

```
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
 QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
 QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
 QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
 QPainter::translate: Painter not active
 QPainter::translate: Painter not active
 QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
 QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
 QPainter::translate: Painter not active
 QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
 QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
 QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
 (Parent is Oxygen::WidgetStateEngine(0x282cdc0), parent's thread is QThread(0x141baf0), current thread is QThread(0x2a87e60)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have changed the code to add a proper example. Since I am not plotting in the main thread it is giving multiple warnings. If I had just added my run() function commands to the oh_no function and removed the thread pool commands. it was working fine